# "Make an apology" vs "give an apology"

Tags: word-usage

I've seen a BrE textbook stating that only one is correct ("give").
But I don't believe that to be true. Are both correct?
Do they have different usage?
Are there differences between AmE and BrE in this regard? Thanks!

"*make an apology*"
"*give an apology*"

Comment: Your source textbook is opinionated garbage. Ignore it.

Comment: Please give the source so that this may be checked. If your memory is correct, this is a text to be wary of.

Comment: Why is this question labelled as "off-topic" here? Somebody must have lost their mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the more common collocations of verb+apology from [Oxford Collocation Dictionary](https://m.freecollocation.com/browse/apology) :

> (VERB + APOLOGY) ***convey, give sb, issue, make, offer (sb), publish, send (sb)*** *The newpaper has issued an apology to the minister.* | ***get, receive | demand, deserve, expect*** *We expect a full written apology.* | ***owe sb*** *She certainly owes you an apology.* | ***mumble, murmur, mutter*** *John muttered an apology then went back to his book.* | ***accept*** *Please accept my sincere apologies.* | ***reject***. *She rejected my apology, saying it was not enough.*

Give an apology is just less common than make an apology, see [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20an%20apology%2Cgive%20an%20apology&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20an%20apology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20an%20apology%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Hmm, why does this unnamed modern British-origin textbook have students choose either "give" or "make" for the word apology then? And the key states "give" is the correct anser. It's a collocation exercise where only one of them is correct (not both). That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @deLock - don’t know about your source,  mine is a reliable one by the site standards. In any case your book is correct in saying that make an apology is the best choice between the two, but that doesn't  mean that “give” is incorrect. It is simply less commonly used.

Comment: Actually, read my comment again, the book says the opposite -- that "give" is correct. And most importantly, that "give" is THE correct our of the two (which implies that "make" is incorrect).

Comment: @deLock sorry, what book are you talking about?